# Android 23 Not Generating Manifest file for uses-permission elements

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have project with several interdependent modules which we just upgraded to target android-23.

The issue is, the app doesn't seem to generate `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` etc. properties when I use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` in AndroidManifest.

However, it does generate the properties when I do `<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` but this just seems different to any and all examples I've seen.

For reference, our versions are:

```
minSdkVersion = 18
compileSdkVersion = 23
targetSdkVersion  = 23
buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
```

and support libraries are `23.0.1`

Anyone run into this or have any ideas what's going on?

**Update**
Adding the generated file contents I see in `build/generated/source/r/{flavor}/com/example/Manifest.java`

```
public final class Manifest {
    public static final class permission {
        public static final String C2D_MESSAGE="com.example.permission.C2D_MESSAGE";
        public static final String RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE="com.example.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE";
        public static final String UA_DATA="com.example.permission.UA_DATA";
    }
}
```

Comment: "the app doesn't seem to generate" -- what does this mean? "it does generate the properties" -- what are "the properties"? `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is not something that is generated. It is part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Ah I see... there is definitely a generated file which the IDE was importing for me by default. So it seems you have to use android.Manifest for system permissions and {app_package}.Manifest for custom `<permission/>`s. Maybe it was clear in the documentation and I just missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is as intended.

When you add `<permission>` in your manifest, you are **defining** your own permission. So, this is added to the class `<your_package_name>.Manifest`.

However, when you add `<uses-permission>` in your manifest, you are **NOT** defining a new permission, but specifies that you are **requesting** a permission which is already defined by elsewhere (mostly not in your application). So, in this case, the permission is not added to the class `<your_package_name>.Manifest`. Instead, it can be found at `<package_defining_the_permission>.Manifest` class. For the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, it is defined in the package named `android`: http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#540

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
for working with

```
compileSdkVersion = 23
targetSdkVersion  = 23
```

You need to ask permissions at runtime in android.
Refer here to for asking permissions at runtime:- http://coderzpassion.com/android-new-runtime-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

To maybe add even more clarity, to what Jiyong Park mentions.

The `Manifest` you will want to use is

```
android.Manifest.permission
```

and **not**

```
com.myapp.Manifest
```

which you are probably looking at (if you just started type `Manifest`, this is likely what you got since it is in your application package).